# Gradle + rhino execute scripts

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

It is my second gradle using and, I have a little question of how to execute js scripts in gradle.

I tried to do with commandLine and it works fine

```
task optimizeScript(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'java', '-classpath', 'path/to/rhino/js.jar:path/to/closure/compiler.jar', 'org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main', 'r.js', 'main.js'
}
```

But I think there is a better way of using gradle. Maybe I can execute script without commandLine? I think first I can get those dependencies from mvn, and next it is write script like

```
dependencies {
  compile rhino
  compile otherstuff
}

task optimizeScript() {
  org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main('r.js main.js')
}
```

(of course this script doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in the following way:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'rhino:js:1.7R2'   
}

task runJS(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath configurations.compile
   main 'org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main'
   args 'run.js'
   standardOutput = new FileOutputStream(project.file('stdout'))
   errorOutput = new FileOutputStream(project.file('stderr'))
}
```

**run.js**

```
function f(x) {
 return x+1
} 
print(f(7))
```

After running `gradle runJS`, `stdout` file contains *8*.